Serial port overlapped operations returns code 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
I'm trying to set the communication with an arduino nano.
I'm exploring the use of overlapped I/O, this is just a test and I am aware that I have no interest in using overlapped I/O in this state.
I'm using an arduino nano that sends a character ("p") every seconds with the Serial.print.
I'm calling the WaitCommEvent in a loop.
My issue is, if I remove the call to the Sleep before the WaitCommEvent, the character sent by the arduino isn't displayed anymore.
Here is an abstract of how my code works :

Open the comm port by calling CreateFile with the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag.
Call the setCommMask, setCommTimeout
Create the appropriate event in the Overlapped structure
Call WaitCommEvent with the overlapped structure.
Then WaitForSingleObject on the event.
ReadFile when the event is signaled.

    BOOL   Status; // Status

    // Defining COM port id
    const wchar_t PortNo[20] = L"\\\\.\\COM4";
    //Open the serial com port
    HANDLE hComm;  // Handle to the Serial port
    printf("Openning %ls\n", PortNo);
    hComm = CreateFile(PortNo, //friendly name
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,      // Read/Write Access
        0,                                 // No Sharing, ports cant be shared
        NULL,                              // No Security
        OPEN_EXISTING,                     // Open existing port only
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,                                 // Non Overlapped I/O
        NULL);                             // Null for Comm Devices
    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf_s("\n Port %ls can't be opened\n\n", PortNo);
    }
    //Setting the Parameters for the SerialPort
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };  // Initializing DCB structure
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams); //retreives  the current settings

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;      //BaudRate = 9600
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             //ByteSize = 8
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    //StopBits = 1
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;      //Parity = None
    Status = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(Status, __LINE__);

    //Setting Timeouts
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };  //Initializing timeouts structure
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError to Setting Time outs");
        CloseHandle(hComm);
    }

    DWORD BytesWritten = 0;          // No of bytes written to the port

    DWORD dwEventMask;     // Event mask to trigger
    DWORD NoBytesRead;     // Bytes read by ReadFile()
    int index = 0;
    OVERLAPPED o = { 0 };
    o.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (o.hEvent == NULL)
        return FALSE; // Error creating overlapped event handle.
    assert(o.hEvent);
    DWORD dwRes;
    while (1) {
          Status = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR); 
        if (Status == FALSE)
        {
            printf_s("\nError to in Setting CommMask\n\n");
            CloseHandle(hComm);
        }
        //Setting WaitComm() Event
        char  ReadData[100] = { 0 };        //temporary Character

        Status = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, &o); //Wait for the character to be received
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            printf("IO_NOT_PENDING %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
        DWORD lpModemStat;
        dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(o.hEvent, INFINITE);
        switch (dwRes) {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

            if (dwEventMask & EV_RXCHAR) {
                Status = ReadFile(hComm, &ReadData, sizeof(ReadData), &NoBytesRead, &o);
                ResetEvent(o.hEvent);
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    std::cout << ReadData[i];
                }
            }
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

I put the setCommMask in the loop because if I don't, I get an error on the WaitCommeEvent that returns the code 87 - The parameter is incorrect.
I think there is something wrong with the way I use the functions or in my understanding.

The event needs to be reset after each use so it can be signaled again.
So add ResetEvent(o.hEvent).  dwEventMask = NULL is weird, it is not a pointer.  Btw, no point in using overlapped I/O when you are going to call WaitForSingleObject() right away, nothing is getting overlapped.

I tried putting ResetEvent(o.hEvent) right before the WaitCommEvent and still had the issue.
I added the dwEventMask = NULL just in case it would change something (forgot to remove it).
I get that there is no use in using overlapped I/O in this maner but, I'm fiddling with the thing to learn.

@HansPassant WaitCommEvent() resets the event object before returning, so there is no need to reset it manually

@l_KarmaKat You didn't show how hComm or the OVERLAPPED are being setup prior to calling WaitCommEvent(). This is not a [mcve]. Also, the dwRead value reported by GetOverlappedResult() is undefined for a WaitCommEvent() operation, so just ignore it. But, don't ignore the NoBytesRead value that ReadFile() reports.

Thank you @RemyLebeau, I'm going to ignore the result from GetOverlappedResult.
Actually after removing wEventMask = NULL it seems to be working as expected...
I don't understand why this issue was only showing up when the arduino would send 1 char per second, but would disappear when I let the arduino send as many characters as it could.

@l_KarmaKat You should still call GetOverlappedResult() to make sure OVERLAPPED and dwEventMask are updated correctly. You just don't need the dwRead value that is reported. Also, you are calling SetCommMask() before entering the loop, then calling SetCommMask() again inside the loop before calling WaitCommEvent(). Don't double-call SetCommMask() like that. Also, WaitForSingleObject(..., INFINITE); GetOverlappedResult(..., FALSE); can be replaced with simply GetOverlappedResult(... TRUE); instead - notice the last parameter.

Thank you for that piece of information.
Regarging the double call I had forgotten to remove the initial call.
Is it still correct to call SetCommMask in every iteration ?
I don't understand why but if I don't do it, WaitCommEvent return an error code "87 - The Parameter is Incorrect"

So, after a few hours I found to interseting links that helped a lot :

An old MSDN guide
A github gist

while (true)
    {
        // Issue a status event check if one hasn't been issued already.
        if (!fWaitingOnStat)
        {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Calling WaitCommEvent\n");
            if (!WaitCommEvent(port, &dwCommEvent, &osStatus))
            {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                {
                    fWaitingOnStat = TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error in WaitCommEvent\n");
                    break; // abort
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Read data
            }
        }

        // Check on overlapped operation.
        if (fWaitingOnStat)
        {
            DWORD dwOvRes;

            DWORD dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osStatus.hEvent, 100);
            switch(dwRes)
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                // Event occurred.
                if (!GetOverlappedResult(port, &osStatus, &dwOvRes, FALSE))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error from GetOverlappedResult\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Read data
                }
                fWaitingOnStat = FALSE;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Error in WaitForSingleObject\n");
                CloseHandle(osStatus.hEvent);
                return 70;
            }
        }
    }

It helped me understand what I was supposed to do and removed the weird behaviour I was facing.
